# Debugging Sling/Sightly server-side JavaScript

Tags: rhino, aem, jcr, sling, sightly

I am trying to debug JavaScript that is stored in the JCR and run on the server with Rhino, by the Sightly templating language's [JavaScript UseAPI](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html).

As per the instructions provided in [sling.properties](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/tags/org.apache.sling.launchpad.base-2.3.0/src/main/resources/sling.properties):

```
# To enable the current server side debugging in the Rhino interpreter
# set the org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript.debug property to true.
# This will open a Swing window for Rhino JavaScript debugging on the
# server platform.
```

When I do this, I can see the Swing window for Rhino. However, if I try to set a breakpoint on a JavaScript file, or trigger the debugger by adding a `debugger;` line, the debugger breaks but does not show me the correct file.

Similarly, if I select 'Break on function enter' from the Debug menu, the debugger will break but using 'Step Into/Over/Out' seems to jump to random points in the code.

Is this working for anyone else? I'm using v2.0.14 of org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript which seems to be the latest.

Comment: How do you set org.apache.sling.scripting.javascript.debug to true? Is that in the web console? Thanks.

Comment: you need to edit the sling.properties file for your AEM instance

Comment: Did you find a solution for debugging javascript backend?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I spoke to Adobe a few times too and it didn't seem like something they were doing themselves either, or something they planned to add support for.

Answer (score 1):

As you already alluded to in one of your comments, it appears this feature hasn't actually been implemented.

[Here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly.html) on the main Sightly docs they list the following **con** for using the javascript Use API over the Java Use API:

> no debugger (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Since the rhino script finally compiles to a java class, you can add `java.lang.System.out.println("Resource path: " + resource.getPath())` statements and log values for debugging purpose, you should see the values written to `crx-quickstart/logs/stdout.log`